# generate fingerprint of client using javascript

Tags: javascript, unique

How can i generate unique fingerprint of each client?

I know must use `navigator` object but some properties like `navigator.battery` cannot use in this method.

```
// battery included and unique may change.
var uniqueHash = exampleHash(JSON.stringify(navigator));
```

How can i generate correct unique fingerprint for each user just using JavaScript and without cookie.

Cross platform and older browser also must be included.

I need list of cross browser supported by `navigator.X`

**Note:**
I don't want to generate random hash. i want to generate system base hash for each user and i dont wanna save on Cookie or Storage.

Comment: You mean uniquely identifying the surfing user, even if he/she deletes cookies and such?

Comment: @esseks question updated. See note.

Comment: Please rephrase the question, I cannot understand what you are asking. You mean to generate an hash which identifies the combination of User Agent + Screen Size + etc. and keep it across all requests without using cookies?

Comment: @esseks yeah. correct question if have any ambiguous

Comment: Is this for tracking the user or, for example, for serving different versions of the site based on specific capabilities (screen width...)?

Comment: @esseks yeah i need this for tracking using in some web sites as same tracking system so i havnt any cookie or local storage. so i need the simple mechanism for get unique hash for each user visit my website. by using their pc, browser and etc information **that supported by all browsers and not dependence on somthing like battery or similar value**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29498/discussion-between-sweb-and-esseks)

Answer (score 2):

> How can i generate unique fingerprint of each client?

Short answer is that you can't. It's impossible to do this for every client. You can get close using [invasive profiling](http://symcbean.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/im-currently-spending-significant.html) of the client, but you'll probably only get a unique identifier in around 90-95% of cases.

> and i dont wanna save on Cookie or Storage.

Is there a reason you don't want to store data client side? If you told us what you were trying to achieve then maybe we could suggest a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: The reason is most probably fingerprinting a client for use with google universal analitics to work around EU cookie law :)

Comment: https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2018/06/gdpr-and-browser-fingerprinting-how-it-changes-game-sneakiest-web-trackers

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to keep a session without using cookies is appending a unique hash (maybe a UUID or something similar) to the urls in the page as a get parameter:

```
/my/fancy/url
```

becomes

```
/my/fancy/url?HASHCODE
```

whenever the server receives a request, it capture the HASHCODE if present, otherwise it generates one, and then append it to all links on the served page.

Please bear in mind that the user can manipulate the HASHCODE and you should take that into account when engineering your application.

Anyway, notice that it's quite ugly in the fancy-url era. Also notice that user tracking is a delicate subject and you might incur into legal problems if you do not properly declare it in the TOS.

EDIT: you **cannot** track a person across multiple web sites without using cookies in any of their variants (flash, session storage, etc.) and a domain shared between sites. No way, you cannot set a variable or cookie from one domain and access it from another one in any decent browser, otherwise it would be a big security hole.

EDIT: Panopticlick cannot be used as a tracking method as you suggested, because it is based on statistical matching and it is also pretty bad at that (try browsing https://panopticlick.eff.org/ from outside the USA or with the just-released Chrome/Firefox update). It's a good proof concept, but nothing that you can use for this purpose. Also, you would need a whole lot of samples to get statistically relevant results.

EDIT: Browser fingerprint identifying power is weak: many browsers are autoupdating (like Chrome or Firefox) and official builts are very few (20? 40? Maybe a bit more if you count Linux distribution-compiled ones), so you will find a consistent portion of users with the same user agent. Add that there is a pletora of consumer PCs with similar configurations.

Comment: This would certainly work, but the fingerprint would be different anytime a user starts a new session

Comment: Since he does not want to use cookies, there is no chance at all to keep ID across sessions.

Comment: Not solely with javascript anyways

Answer (score 1):

One route that may be worth looking into is using the [Mozilla Persona API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/persona).  It exposes a `navigator.id` property for consumption.  Getting a unique id from a user is as simple as...

```
navigator.id.get(function(unique_id) {
    alert("this is your unique id: " + unique_id);
})
```

This has the downside of requiring user authorization

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/aJsL9/1/

Comment: Persona sets a cookie under the hood, so it's just like using cookies on the OP's domain.