# stop user copy and paste cookies in other browser for login in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, cookies, multiple-login

I have an application in Codeigniter a simple login form.
if the user login in browse (A) and copy the login cookies.
Now paste this cookie in browser (B) the user is login without any authentication
how can stop this.

Comment: It would help to show the "essential" code on how you proceed your login. Is it your own authentication code or are you using some 3rd party library? Also, did you verify if user A is logged out, user B can still use your mentioned technique to log in?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a technique called [finger printing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint), to create a checksum of the browser when the user initially logs in, then at certain points, you can check if the fingerprint is the same as before.

Some related resources are

- https://coveryourtracks.eff.org/
- http://browserspy.dk/
- https://fingerprintjs.com/

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It is highly appreciated if any open source solution is available.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402285/generate-fingerprint-of-client-using-javascript  , there are plenty of open source solutiosn available and it is otherwise very easy to make a simple fingerprint solution